# XSL 2.0 reference value in parent for-each-group from embedded for-each-group

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have XML that looks like this:

```
<DATA>
  <GROUP_ACCT>123456</GROUP_ACCT>
  <GROUP_DESC>Example</GROUP_DESC>
  <CHILD_ACCT>12345678</CHILD_ACCT>
  <CHILD_DESC>Example - Acct 1</CHILD_DESC>
</DATA>
<DATA>
  <GROUP_ACCT>234567</GROUP_ACCT>
  <GROUP_DESC>Example2</GROUP_DESC>
  <CHILD_ACCT>23456789</CHILD_ACCT>
  <CHILD_DESC>Example2 - Acct 1</CHILD_DESC>
</DATA>
```

I have code that looks like this:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="DATA" group-by="concat(GROUP_ACCT, '|', GROUP_DESC)">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></td>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="DATA" group-by="concat(CHILD_ACCT, '|', CHILD_DESC)">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="current-group()/../current-grouping-key()"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

In this example I'm trying to access the parent element's current-grouping-key(), but I can seem to get it to work from the embedded `for-each-group`

Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: Can you post what your expected output is? I don't really get what you are trying to do. Your first for-each-group selects DATA elements, then when inside of the for-each-group your context becomes that group. You can't select DATA from that group (you can but it won't select anything).

Comment: Downvoting. Read the question again: the only way we can understand your requirement is by reading the code that doesn't meet it.

Answer (score 0):

Your example makes no sense to me - the following is based on a speculation regarding what your question is really about.

You seem to think that if you nest two `xsl:for-each-group` instructions, the outer group and its properties become available on the parent axis. That is not so. The only node available on the parent axis is the node that is the parent of the context item **in the original XML**.

If you want to access the grouping key of the outer group from within the inner group, put it in a variable before calling the inner  `xsl:for-each-group` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want something like this, but you haven't made the requirements very clear:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="DATA" group-by="concat(GROUP_ACCT, '|', GROUP_DESC)">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></td>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="concat(CHILD_ACCT, '|', CHILD_DESC)">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```